# VBA Copy sheets to new workbook - with/without formulas

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, copy, formula

I use this code to copy 4 sheets to separate workbook. One of them - "1" have formulas inside, method below skips those formulas. Any ideas how to keep three workbook's as value only and one - "1" including the formulas? Part of code responsible for that action below. Thank you in advance.

```
Sub test()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Fname As String, ws As Worksheet
Dim InitFileName As String, fileSaveName As String
Fname = Sheets("STRUCTURE").Range("A1").Value
Sheets(Array("STRUCTURE", "2", "3", "1")).Copy
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws.UsedRange
        .Value = .Value
    End With
Next ws
With ActiveWorkbook
fileSaveName = "FILE LOCATION FOLDER " & Sheets("STRUCTURE").Cells(1, 1) & ".xlsx"
    .SaveAs fileSaveName
    .Close
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Create an array of the worksheets to loop over, instead of looping over `Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`?

Comment: @BigBen thank you for your comment, could you please show me exactly what should i change  - on the code? This will be super helpfull since im stucked with that and no mater how i changed the code it keeped the values only or crashed, this change seems to be above my skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what is changing formulas to values:

```
With ws.UsedRange
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

You have several options to skip the worksheet in question:

1. Skip the worksheet named `1`.

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "1" Then
        With ws.UsedRange
            .Value = .Value
        End With
   End If
Next
```

2. Only loop over the worksheets in question:

```
Dim sheetNamesToProcess As Variant
sheetNamesToProcess = Array("STRUCTURE", "2", "3")

Dim i As Long
For i = Lbound(sheetNamesToProcess) To Ubound(sheetNamesToProcess)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetNamesToProcess(i)).UsedRange
        .Value = .Value
    End With
Next
```